# Is there a problem with applications under Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: netbeans, 23.04

Recently, I set up **Ubuntu 23.04** instead of **Windows 10**, and some applications (Apache Netbeans 17, TMCBeans, VLCmedia "using **sudo snap [*name*]"** ) are not opening when I click them.
Is this problem with Ubuntu new version or another reason? What can I do ? And If problem will be Ubuntu 23.04 , can I install another ubuntu version via terminal without any data losing? Thank you for your answears.

Comment: "Some problem" and "applications not opening" are rather vague problem descriptions. First, how did you install those applications? Which errors do you get when trying to run them? Which troubleshooting steps did you already follow?

Comment: Sorry, I install them via terminal. No problem with installing. Nothing happened when i click on them. I mean i can't enter these apps. That's it.

Comment: I installed VLC from Ubuntu Software and it seems to work fine. Why do it from terminal?

Comment: I just like typing so I installed them via terminal

Comment: but what commands did you use to install - all of them. Installing from Ubuntu Software is more likely to guarantee that all dependencies are included but from the command line more often needs to be done. [edit] in to your question

Comment: "sudo snap install netbeans"

Comment: comments are for responders to seek further information in order to assist you.  Do not add further information pertaining to your question to the comment trail [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take them one by one in the Snap Store.

1. [Netbeans](https://snapcraft.io/netbeans). The command to install via terminal is:

   ```
   sudo snap install netbeans --classic
   ```
2. [TMCBeans](https://snapcraft.io/tmcbeans). The command to install via terminal is:

   ```
   sudo snap install tmcbeans --classic
   ```
3. [VLC](https://snapcraft.io/vlc). The command to install via terminal is:

   ```
   sudo snap install vlc
   ```

So 2 out of the 3 apps need to be installed with "[classic confinement](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)".

Please try following the instructions given, and see if it helps.

Comment: I installed all of them but they aren't working.

Comment: You need to provide more troubleshooting information than "they aren't working". For starters, try including elements from `/var/log/syslog` when you start the applications.